# Inverse operation for a yaml merge such as yq multiply?

Tags: merge, command-line, yaml, yq

Many application read several input files and merge them logically such that inputs with higher priority override previously read fields.

For yaml files, we can achieve this logic using a merge command such as (unsing [Go yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)):

```
yq '. *= load("special.yaml")' base.yaml > merged.yaml
```

For a `base.yaml`:

```
a:
  - foo
  - bar
b:
  foo: bar
```

and `special.yaml`:

```
b:
  foo: SPECIAL
  bar: SPECIAL
c:
  - SPECIAL
```

This yields as `merged.yaml`:

```
a:
  - foo
  - bar
b:
  foo: SPECIAL
  bar: SPECIAL
c:
  - SPECIAL
```

The task at hand is to reverse this operation:

Given `merged.yaml` and `base.yaml`, derive a file that only contains the subset of `merged.yaml` not in `base.yaml`. The result then can be plugged into the command above as `special.yaml` to recreate `merged.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which of the two implementations of yq you are using (see the [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) to [yq](/questions/tagged/yq)).

With [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), you can break up the scalars of both documents into their stream representation (paths and values) using `tostream`, then subtract one from the other, and iteratively re-assemble the remaining difference using `setpath`:

```bash
yq -sy '
  reduce (map([tostream | select(has(1))]) | .[0] - .[1])[] as $i
    (null; setpath($i[0]; $i[1]))
' merged.yaml base.yaml
```

```yaml
b:
  foo: SPECIAL
  bar: SPECIAL
c:
  - SPECIAL
```

This solution also works with [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq), using the flags `gojq -s --yaml-input --yaml-output`.

---

Edit:

> Adds linkt to Go yq
>
> > unsing [Go yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)

You could convert the approach from above into a [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) filter by manually breaking up the documents' scalars into their paths and values using `..` and `path`, and then just perform the same subtraction and the same iterative re-assembly:

```bash
yq ea '
  [[.. | select(kind == "scalar") | [path, .]]] | .[0] - .[1]
  | .[] as $i ireduce(null; setpath($i[0]; $i[1]))
' merged.yaml base.yaml
```

```yaml
b:
  foo: SPECIAL
  bar: SPECIAL
c:
  - SPECIAL
```